# Convex contains all convex combination

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A$ a convex subset of vector space $V$, $v_1,...,v_m \in A$ and $x_1,...,x_m \geq 0$ such that $\sum x_k =1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{m} x_k v_k \in A$

How can I prove this, I don't know how to begin this, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try using induction on $m$. Note that a convex combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ is a convex combination of (a convex combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_{m-1}$) and $v_m$.